# How to display video in/with Adobe Alchemy?

Tags: c++, video, air, adobe, alchemy

I want to display a video from a not supported USB camera in Air (or Flash).
There is a SDK (of the camera) to display the video stream.

My question:
How should the C/C++ routine build to compile it with [Adobe Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/)?
I want only to display the video stream in Adobe Air (or Flash).
No audio or something special is needed - only video.

I am working on Linux.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot already use the camera from Flash, Alchemy is not going to help you.

Alchemy can only do things that ActionScript can do-- it *does not* help you "get around" the Flash sandbox.  The reason people use Alchemy is so that they can compile large legacy codebases and/or open-source libraries.

Comment: Mhh why? Someone told me, that he used a Camera SDK and compiled it for Air/Flash. In the SDK is a method to get the videostream. Flash/Air doesn't support the camera because there is at the moment no driver (for linux [Video4Linux2]).

Comment: I think you need to read the [Alchemy FAQ](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:FAQ).  Alchemy cross-compiles C/C++ into AVM bytecode that runs inside of an emulated C runtime.  That is, your C/C++ code is turned into the same bytecode that ActionScript is turned into.  So, if you can't already do it in AS you can't do it with Alchemy.  You can't write an operating system driver with Alchemy.